# NGINX server with 2 NodeJS Apps

Tags: node.js, nginx, webserver, google-cloud-platform

I will make it short without introductions ..

I'm having a serious issues with NGINX configuration (on google cloud) to make 2 nodejs apps working on the same domain with different PORTS

let's say app1 is working on port 3002, app2 working on port 3003

**app1**

```
    location / {
        root /home/bitnami/project_name;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3002;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
```

**app2**

```
   location /app2 {
        root /home/bitnami/project_name;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3003;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
```

when I surf www.example.com/app2, I get 404 page

I know some of u will say that this Q has been asked before, believe me I've tried all possible solutions on stackoverflow .. non has worked with me

Note: app1 location it has to be the main domain so (/) the main domain URL without path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your code does not use relative paths, thats why you are getting this error, add this line:

```
rewrite ^/app2(.*) /$1 break;
```

and no root required for proxy pass, your new code shall look like this:

```
location /app2 {
    #root /home/bitnami/project_name;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3003;
    #proxy_http_version 1.1;
    #proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    #proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    #proxy_redirect off;
    rewrite ^/app2(.*) /$1 break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first `location` block captures requests for all requests of your domain, leaving the second block never used. Put the second block before the first one and it should work.

Comment: so u suggest that I reverse the order .. and that's it?

Comment: same thing .. i get a 404 page

Comment: does the 404 comes from nginx or the node process?